# Mouse release triggers 'onClick' event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onclick

Suppose I have the following React component:

```
<div onClick={closeModal} id='modal'>
      <div onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} id='modal_content'>
            {children}
      </div>
</div>
```

where #modal is the parent and #modal_content is the children. Clicking on #modal would close the modal. Because of that #modal_content stops the propogation so only clicking on #modal actually closes the modal.
[image]
And now the problem: If I press down the mouse while it's over #modal_content and then release the mouse when it's over #modal, onClick event attached to the #modal triggers closing the modal. I.e I'm actually listening to mouse release instead of a full click process(press & release). How can I make #modal to listen to a full mouse click instead of mouse release only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay seems like I needed a wrapper around and put the event on it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).